# HTML input type time not working in firefox

Tags: html, razor

Below perfectly works in Chrome not in Mozilla Firefox (23.0.1)

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new { type = "time"})
```

Is there any  hack to make it work in Firefox . Or else, what could be the possible solution for that.

Comment: It's not supported in Firefox : http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/att_input_type.asp

Answer (score 4):

Please refer below link,

http://www.miketaylr.com/code/input-type-attr.html

Fyi: If `textbox` is red then that type is not supported for that particular browser.